# How to boot Ubuntu in complete darkness?

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader

Is there a way to load Ubuntu without the splash screen or verbose mode?

That means no visual queues or code reporting.

Is this possible?

**Known settings in the grub loader:**

Verbose Mode

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
```

Splash welcome screen

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Comment: Did you try `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"`?

Comment: Yes, it also enables console messages.

Comment: Looks like the kenel, grub and init all [need help](http://www.refining-linux.org/archives/4/Boot-your-Linux-silently/) being quiet. I found this by searching for "ubuntu boot suppress console 2015" which has other good hints. There was an old 2009 article but I don't know if all that hassle is necessary now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tutorial:
http://www.howtogeek.com/196655/how-to-configure-the-grub2-boot-loaders-settings/

When editing your grub file, this option should be enougth to load automatically your first boot option:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

After changing your grub file, apply changes with the command

```
sudo update-grub
```

Hope this helps you.